# On average, how many more digits do octal numbers have than decimal numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, statistics, number-systems

My question is, how could I calculate the expected value of the number of digits of an octal representation of an $n$-digit decimal number?

How can this question be answered in general for two different bases? E.g., how many more digits would base-9 numbers have than base-12 numbers on average?

Comment: To clarify, are you counting the set of $2$-digit decimal numbers as $10, 11, \ldots, 98, 99$, or are you including $0, 1, \ldots, 9$?

Comment: $\log_b b'$---the proof is essentially the same as in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/936445/155629

Comment: Yeah, the discussion Travis Willse linked is the answer to this question.

Comment: @BrianMoehring all natural numbers

Comment: @TravisWillse thank you, I couldn't find that